# Can javafx application display different stages on different monitors?

Tags: javafx

The idea is to have one app displaying two diferent windows (Stages) one on each monitor, the app should know how many monitors the computer has and their resolution.

It is possible with javafx?

Answer (score 5):

For the current version of JavaFX (2.2) you can use this:

```
Screen.getScreens()
```

That will give you an observable list of Screen objects.

See the Screen javadoc page here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with JavaFX but if I am not mistaken it's JDK is sort of a superset of Java JDK.

the java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment class can be used to get the different graphics devices which the Graphics2D methods output to.